# Display message in view when back button tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 `UIViewController`'s wrapped in a `UINavigationController`

From the 2nd `UIViewController`, when the users taps the back button, I want to display a message in the 1st `UIViewController`.

Is there a way to capture this event, then react in the `UIViewController`?

Comment: If you want more than that, you should be telling us what you've already tried, showing us some code, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is with an unwind segue, which is also your chance to grab data from the second viewController before it gets destroyed. In ViewController1 add:

```
    @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let source = segue.source as? SecondViewController {
            //grab any data you need here and set your message up
        }
    }
```

In your story board ctrl+drag from your yellow view controller to the orange exit to create an unwindSegue and link it to prepareForUnwind (these icons are both on top of the view controller and in the outline view to the left).  Give your segue an identifier like "unwindSecondViewController".

In SecondViewController.  In viewWillDisappear or when you dismiss the view manually add in:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSecondViewController", sender: self)
```